# Data state with multiple values but only one can be to true in a Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a Vue.js app where the user can choose the payment method clicking on 3 buttons (Credit card, Paypal, Iban). Each ones call the method `setPayment(type)` where `type` is the choosen payment method (cc, paypal, iban).

Below is the code. Look at the method `setPayment(type)`: is there a way to avoid to set to `false` everytime the other 2 payment. The code is working but I think it's too much verbose and dirty.

Or maybe there is another better way to do the whole thing?

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  //
  // Data
  //
  data: {

    payment: {
      cc: true,
      paypal: false,
      iban: false
    }

  },

  //
  // Methods
  //
  methods: {

    // Set payment
    setPayment: function(type) {
      if (type == 'cc'){
        this.payment.cc = true;
        this.payment.paypal = false;
        this.payment.iban = false;
      }
      if (type == 'paypal'){
        this.payment.cc = false;
        this.payment.paypal = true;
        this.payment.iban = false;
      }
      if (type == 'iban'){
        this.payment.cc = false;
        this.payment.paypal = false;
        this.payment.iban = true;
      }
    }

  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn `payment` into a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) and use a `selectedPayment` type.

```
payment(){
  return {
    cc: this.selectedPayment === 'cc',
    paypal: this.selectedPayment === 'paypal',
    iban: this.selectedPayment === 'iban'
  }
}
```

Example.

```js
console.clear()
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selectedPayment: null,
  },
  computed: {
    payment(){
      return {
        cc: this.selectedPayment === 'cc',
        paypal: this.selectedPayment === 'paypal',
        iban: this.selectedPayment === 'iban'
      }
    }
  },
  methods:{
    onSelectPayment(type){
      this.selectedPayment = type
      // do other stuff. If you need the payment, it is available
      // as this.payment
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Payment: {{payment}}
  <hr>
  <button @click="onSelectPayment('cc')">CC</button>
  <button @click="onSelectPayment('paypal')">PayPal</button>
  <button @click="onSelectPayment('iban')">Iban</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Bert, very interesting, I didn't know the computed property and don't get it at all but it does what I need. Could you give me some explanations? Thanks

Comment: @FredK Computed properties are fundamental in Vue. I added a link to the documentation. Basically computed properties are typically a value derived from other data. Common use cases are filtering, sorting, and mapping one set of data into another. In this case your data structure for `payment` can be derived from a `selectedPayment`.

Comment: I've seen it, but if I need to do other operations when the user click a button, where I can place them? With dedicated methods (as in my first post) I can put other operations inside each `if`. Can i do this with computed property too? And if yes, is it anyway better than methods, for my case?

Comment: @FredK Updated to use a method. As for whether it is better; it clarifies your code considerably in my opinion.